# zend_soap_server utf-8 encoding does not work

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, wsdl, zend-soap

I am developing a soap webservice using `zend_soap_server`.
I use `Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover` to auto generate wsdl of my webservice.

Here is the code

> ```
> public function indexAction() { // my websrvice method
>
>       $server = new Zend_Soap_Server("admin/webservice/wsdl");
>       
>       $server->setEncoding('UTF-8');
>
>       $server->setClass('Webservice');
>
>       $server->handle();
> }
>
> public function wsdlAction() { // my wsdl method
>
>       $wsdl = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
>
>       $wsdl->setClass('Webservice');
>
>       $wsdl->setUri("/admin/webservice");
>
>       $wsdl->handle();
> }
> ```

My problem is that when i view the source of generated wsdl the first line is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

But i want the encoding in the xml tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

What should i do to get this?

Thx in advance.

Comment: What version of PHP and Zend Framework are you using? The reason I ask is because I tried a simple test without the call to `setMethod()` and I got the encoding attribute by default. I am running PHP 5.3.8 and ZF 1.12. The reason the PHP version might matter is because `Zend_Soap` and it's siblings are basically just a wrapper around PHP's native SOAP classes.

Comment: I am using php 5.4.13 and ZF 1.12

Comment: Oh, I just realised I wasn't looking at the WSDL output, I was looking at the request and the response XML, which both contained the encoding. I have a new thought, which I will add as a potential answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the Zend Framework code and it would appear that the first line of the WSDL is hard-coded:

```
    $wsdl = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>
            <definitions name='$name' targetNamespace='$uri'
                xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
                xmlns:tns='$uri'
                xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
                xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
                xmlns:soap-enc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
                xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'></definitions>";
```

The above snippet of code is from line 91 of `Zend/Soap/Wsdl.php`. So the simple fix to your problem is to modify the first line of the above code to include the encoding:

```
    $wsdl = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

I just ran this code and it achieved the desired outcome. And I wouldn't be too fussed about having to modify the framework code. I have a standard set of patches that I've been running over the top of ZF1 ever since about 1.7 to fix a few little oddities that I didn't agree with. That's the beauty of open source - you don't have to pay some company thousands of dollars to make a one-line change! Just make sure you remember to re-run your patch if you ever upgrade to the next maintenance release of ZF1 (assuming one comes along).